# Form undefined using Flask-Security

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms, flask-security

I am using Flask-Security with custom templates for my login forms. I have my form defined but for whatever reason the form isnt being passed to the template.

Here is the form code

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = TextField('Email Address', [
            Required(message='Forgot your email address?')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [
            Required(message='Must provide a password. ;-)')])
```

Here is the template code

```
<form method="POST" action="." accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
    {{ form.csrf_token }} {{ render_field(form.email, placeholder="Your Email Address", autofocus="") }} {{ render_field(form.password, placeholder="Password") }}
        <div>
            <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember Me
                    </label>
                        <a role="button" href="">Forgot your password?</a><span class="clearfix"></span>
        </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>        
</form>
```

Here is the code for the login

```
@mod_auth.route('/signin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    # If sign in form is submitted
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    # Verify the sign in form
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for user in User.objects(email=form.email.data):
            if user and user.password == form.password.data:
                login_user(user)
            if not is_safe_url(next):
                flash('Logging you in')
                return flask.abort(400)
            return redirect(next or ('/')
        elif user:
            flash('Wrong password')
        else:
            flash('could not find username')
    return render_template("security/login_user.html", form=form)
```

The code works if I remove the line in the config

```
app.config['SECURITY_LOGIN_URL'] = '/auth/signin/'
```

But when that line is there it throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/decorators.py", line 230, in wrapper
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/views.py", line 89, in login
**_ctx('login'))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/core.py", line 528, in render_template
return render_template(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
context, ctx.app)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 116, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/kenton/Programming/bridal/bridal-website/becomeOne/app/templates/security/login_user.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}
File "/home/kenton/Programming/bridal/bridal-website/becomeOne/app/templates/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% block doc -%}
File "/home/kenton/Programming/bridal/bridal-website/becomeOne/app/templates/base.html", line 4, in block "doc"
{%- block html %}
File "/home/kenton/Programming/bridal/bridal-website/becomeOne/app/templates/base.html", line 43, in block "html"
{% block body -%}
File "/home/kenton/Programming/bridal/bridal-website/becomeOne/app/templates/base.html", line 48, in block "body"
{% block content -%} {%- endblock content %} {% block scripts %}
File "/home/kenton/Programming/bridal/bridal-website/becomeOne/app/templates/security/login_user.html", line 22, in block "content"
{% endif %} {% endwith %} {% if form.errors %}
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

Any thoughts or help at all would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use Flask-Security, Why do you deal with login yourself?

Comment: @stamaimer well I saw that security used flask login for logins and I never saw anything on how to do the login so I went to flask login and setup something resembles their documentation. How should I be doing the logins

Comment: Have you ever browse the [quick start](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html) of Flask-Security?

Comment: @stamaimer Yeah been through the quick start and a lot of the other documentation. There is nothing about how to setup the login thats why I went to flask-logins documentation for that.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that you need to pass this through another method to the security variable. I know this is old but might help people. Took me a while to work this one out.

```
@app.security.login_context_processor
def login_context_processor():
    return dict(form=LoginForm())
```

You need to look at this part of the docs

> Each template is passed a template context object that includes the
> following, including the objects/values that are passed to the
> template by the main Flask application context processor:
>
> <template_name>_form: A form object for the view
>
> security: The Flask-Security extension object
>
> To add more values to the template context, you can specify a context
> processor for all views or a specific view. For example:
>
> security = Security(app, user_datastore)
>
> ## This processor is added to all templates @security.context_processor def security_context_processor():
>
> ```
> return dict(hello="world")
> ```
>
> ## This processor is added to only the register view @security.register_context_processor def
>
> security_register_processor():
> return dict(something="else") The following is a list of all the available context processor decorators:
>
> context_processor: All views
>
> forgot_password_context_processor: Forgot password view
>
> login_context_processor: Login view
>
> mf_recovery_codes_context_processor: Setup recovery codes view
>
> mf_recovery_context_processor: Use recovery code view
>
> register_context_processor: Register view
>
> reset_password_context_processor: Reset password view
>
> change_password_context_processor: Change password view
>
> send_confirmation_context_processor: Send confirmation view
>
> send_login_context_processor: Send login view
>
> mail_context_processor: Whenever an email will be sent
>
> tf_select_context_processor: Two factor select view
>
> tf_setup_context_processor: Two factor setup view
>
> tf_token_validation_context_processor: Two factor token validation
> view
>
> us_signin_context_processor: Unified sign in view
>
> us_setup_context_processor: Unified sign in setup view
>
> wan_register_context_processor: WebAuthn registration view
>
> wan_signin_context_processor: WebAuthn sign in view
>
> wan_verify_context_processor: WebAuthn verify view

Answer (score 0):

Jinja2 is throwing the error :

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

The template code above uses `form` which it doesn't know about.You are not supplying it to the template which uses it.  You have to pass the `form` through for the template which uses it.